# insert datetime in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, datetime

Hello I'm trying to insert a datetime in a sqlite table my code looks like this and is working, but im wondering if theres an easier solution. the columntype is datetime and from what ive read it expects a date of format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

```
var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
var month = DateTime.Now.Month;
var day = DateTime.Now.Day;
var hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
var minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
var seconds = DateTime.Now.Second;
string date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@test", date);
```

thank you

Comment: Can you not simply pass `cmd.Parameters.Add("@test", DateTime.Now` OR if you need to build it from components simply use the relevant constructor when instantiating a new instance of DateTime?

Comment: Ah OK, if it's string, it's string.  I would suggest you better construct the datetime as follows: `string date = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2} {3}:{4}:{5}", year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds);` - It's far more efficient! :-)

Comment: This does not work if some value is less than 10.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using C#...

Custom date and time format strings [are described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This appears to be the format you need:

```
    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Note the capital M's (to get months rather than minutes) and the capital H's (to get time from the 24-hour clock rather than the 12-hour clock).